# Can't setup correct x and y values

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have arrays of coordinates x and y

```
x = new int[18];
y = new int[15];
x[0] = -404;
y[0] = -226;
for (int i = 1; i < 18; i++)
    x[i] = x[i - 1] + 30;
for (int i = 1; i < 15; i++)
    y[i] = y[i - 1] + 30;
```

I setup random coordinates from arrays. But they're incorrect when I start the program. Mostly numbers are out of arrays. Can't understand why. May be I setup position incorrect?

```
int xCor = x[(int)Random.Range(0, x.Length - 1)];
int yCor = y[(int)Random.Range(0, y.Length - 1)];
transform.position = new Vector2(xCor, yCor);
```

I need to setup new coordinates. E.g. x = 24, y = 50.

Apple is out of the green area:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean when you say the coordinates are incorrect?

Comment: @code11 they are out of the arrays values, sometimes not integers (floats)

Comment: It seems it have to do with the local spaces of the objects. Is the transform matrix of the green grid equal to the transform matrix of the apple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [RectTransform.anchoredPosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform-anchoredPosition.html) property instead of transform.position, like this

```
RectTransform rectTransform = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
rectTransform.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(xCor, yCor);
```

You are using a canvas GameObject which doesn't have a normal transform component.

Comment: This helped.Thank you.